# What is the name of this board game?

Tags: identify-this-game, ancient-board-games

I've been trying to find the name of an old and simple board game but I can't seem to be able to. The rules were something in these lines:

2 players

The board has around 10 board squares or holes set in a row

Each player has 4 pieces (I think) that are located in opposite sides of the board.

The initial set up is like this ('1' means player's 1 pieces, '2' player's 2 and _ empty square)

```
1 1 1 1 _ _ 2 2 2 2
```

The goal of the game is to move all your pieces to the other side with rules:

- You can only move one piece and one square at a time
- 2 pieces can't be in the same square
- If you want to move a piece to a square occupied by another piece you jump over any piece and go to the next empty square

So the game could go like this (Sorry I noticed that I started with player 2 when I was halfway through but shouldn't change anything):

```
1 1 1 1 _ _ 2 2 2 2

1 1 1 1 _ 2 _ 2 2 2

_ 1 1 1 1 2 _ 2 2 2

2 1 1 1 1 _ _ 2 2 2

2 _ 1 1 1 1 _ 2 2 2

...
```

Anybody knows what is the name of this game?

Thank you!

**Edit** This is more or less how a few rounds of the game look like. Each rectangle is one turn. Blue is moving from right to left and red from left to right. Also the game ends when a player gets all the pieces on the other side

[image]

Comment: Hey ignatus, this reminded me of [Mancala](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mancala) board game... is your game it? Or at least similar? also vaguely reminded me of peg solitaire

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like the [jumping frogs](https://primefactorisation.com/frogpuzzle/) puzzle.

There are several variants.

- The number of spaces and pieces can vary.
- The number of pieces you can jump over can vary.

As far as I know, this qualifies as a puzzle. But I think you can play this as a game too.

Comment: That´s it! I´m pretty sure I saw it as a 2 player game (you could jump over more than one piece) or maybe I was just doing it wrong all along :D. Thank you so much!